# Swift Firebase. Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, firebase, exc-bad-instruction

If I am correct: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION means that the app crashed because something does not exists. (After googling it and trying to get my head round it)

However I am getting the error:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

When I tried and load another view.

This is the function where the app crashes:

```
 func loginUserNeedsEmailVerification() {

    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    next.isUserLoggedInButNeedsEmail = true
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am calling this function. From another function like so:

```
perform(#selector(loginUserNeedsEmailVerification), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
```

Even though the file exists, I changed the **!** to **?** like so:

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
    next?.isUserLoggedInButNeedsEmail = true
    self.present(next?, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then another error thrown at the last line:

> Value of optional type is not unwrapped.

When I click the little fix it. It changed the code to this:

```
self.present((next?)!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But then that also errors like so:

> optional chain has no effect

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you declaring a global variable with database reference in any of your classes?

Comment: @Dravidian i'm not sure what that has to do with a view controller being presented? and yes I have the standard FIRDatabase.database().reference()

Comment: @JamesG this crash has nothing to do with Firebase. Check whether the `storyboard` property is `nil` or the `UIViewController` instance returned by the `instantiateViewController` method is `nil`

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issue during instantiateViewController, 
but it's a bit difference since I am calling the method from another class.

A common way to see what goes wrong is by setting the `?` as `!` after `storyboard`
like this :
`self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController`

You will likely see this error
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`,
which means that the storyboard is found nil. In my case, I somehow fail to get the existing reference of UIStoryboard (since I called from another class).

The solution I found is to re-declare the UIStoryboard first:
`let next = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController`
I am not sure why this work, because it still does not get a current reference of storyboard, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks sir. You save my time! :)